# I am trying to create a interactive shell

Tags: c, shell-exec

I am trying to create a interactive shell program that prompts the user for a command, parses the command, and then executes it with a child process.  Here is the code that I have but im not sure where to go after this PLEAE HELP !!!!

```
Int shell(char *cmd_str ){
int commandLength=0;
cmd_t command;
commandLength=make_cmd(cmd_str,  command);
cout<< commandLength<<endl;
cout << command.argv[0]<< endl;
if( execvp( command.argv[0], command.argv)==-1)
//if the command it executed nothing runs after this line
{
commandLength=-1;

}else
{
cout<<"work"<<endl;
}
cout<< commandLength<<endl;
return commandLength;


}
```

Comment: You may be in over your head, but here's a start: http://rik0.altervista.org/snippets/csimpleshell.html Just copying code won't help your education though.

Comment: Also, you marked this as c, but you are using `cout` which is c++    Important: c *is not* c++

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `shell()` is being run within a child process called with `fork()`, you'll need to ensure that the parent process properly waits for the child process to terminate. See the `wait(2)` family of functions.

Additionally, you'll want to retrieve the exit status of said child process (again, see `wait(2)`).

You can also try to implement stream redirection. Assuming this is an exercise, I'll leave the additional research on how to implement these things up to the user :) -- look into `dup(2)`.